Flutter CustomScrollView not resizing
I am trying to create an infinite list that does not modify scroll position when adding items at the top or at the bottom of the list. My prototype is comprised of a CustomScrollView  that hosts two SliverLists "Top" and "Bottom" . The problem that i am facing now is that after removing elements from the bottom list the CustomScrollView is not adjusting its size and scroll extent, an empty space remains where the elements of the Bottom list once were. I have prepared a video for you to quickly understand my problem and a diagram for reference also i am providing full source code of the prototype. At this moment i do not know if this is a bug in the flutter framework or i am doing something inappropriately.
video
https://streamable.com/f90f8d
complete source (single file)
https://gist.github.com/iulian0512/3cad8f53a0ea62af6f88d0660380c010

